# (nil can't be coerced into Integer) getting this error when using prawn gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

```
 @@pdf = Prawn::Document.new
 summary='s2_summary'
 @@pdf.text summary.to_s, :align => :left
 @@pdf.text "Dsh Days Breakdown", :align => :center
```

when running the code " @@pdf.text "Dsh Days Breakdown", :align => :center" getting (nil can't be coerced into Integer)  error

Comment: can you show the full error trace. don't use class variables.

Comment: I need to get this value in another function , that is why I use class variables

Comment: could you provide a bit more details. i tried the code above, it works fine. i don't know where this nil is coming from. also, instance variable `@pdf` can be accessed form another function.

Comment: sorry I have some security issues to share the code , it works for me in a single script but fails in rails application

Comment: It works now , I downgraded prawn gem version